# Is there any web-based gantt chart tool that can be setuped by team ourselves?

Tags: gantt-chart

Guys

Is there any web-based gantt chart tool that can be setuped by team ourselves? I know there are a lot web-based Gantt chart tools(e.g. TeamGantt). But it seems they all requires you to store the data on their servers. Is there any tool that can be setup by teams ourselves and it can only be visible in our intranet?

I don't like desktop tools(e.g. OpenProj or GanttProject), because it's difficult to be shared in team members.

Thanks & BR,
Lin Mao

Comment: Don't know if that helps because I never worked with that, but Redmine has a Gantt chart build in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check [jsGanttImproved](https://github.com/jsGanttImproved/jsgantt-improved), because it doesn't require any additional libraries and it is FREE.

Answer (score 2):

You may look at [dhtmlxGantt](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/index.shtml), a JavaScript Gantt chart that can be added on a web page. It's open source (GPL) and allows you to create a customizable, interactive Gantt chart for your app.

(Disclaimer: I work for DHTMLX)

Answer (score 0):

sorry if the answer is too late but I've used two web based gantt charts:

- jsGantt
- Dojo framework + Dojox + dojox.gantt

You can google them easily. They will accept a JSON string with the tasks, resources and dependecies and draw your gantt chart.

Probably will need some coding to adjust to your environment.